# How to Monitor and edit images on shared hosting server?

Tags: .net, web-applications, hosting

Just want advice on how to think and do the following,
I am creating a website and the user will setup some settings on his profile "images size", then using this settings i want him to point to a folder on his server and my service will monitor and any image upload in this folder i will re size based on settings he saved
I first thought to let the user download a dll file then upload in this folder and it will handle resizing, but the problem that dll is not self running, and user must call it, so its tricky for some users, and also will not work for non windows hosting website.
 also i thought in a webservice but this will take big time and bandwidth to send images and receive again.
Any ideas how to do so?
My website is coded in asp.net 3.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shared hosting is going to make this a difficult problem to solve. If you had more control you could write a Windows Service that watches these folders and does the re-size. I think your best bet is to have the users upload through your application and then resize the image before saving it to the folder.